# Webpack 3.5.5 error loading CSS and SASS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am currently updating my nodejs packages and updated webpack to 3.5.5 and the build is now failing on trying to load css and sass. This is how my loaders look.

```
 loaders: [
  {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader']},
  {test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/, loader: "file-loader" },
  {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]-loader'},
  {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]-loader'},
  {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css?sourceMap-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass?sourceMap-loader']},
]
```

I am wondering if I need to change anything so that these loaders will work?
The error I am getting is

> BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders. You need to specify 'css-loader' instead of 'css', see webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/… `

Comment: What is the output/error message when you run `webpack`?

Comment: BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'css-loader' instead of 'css',
                 see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed

Comment: So where you have `css?sourceMap-loader`, try instead using `css-loader?sourceMap`.

Comment: And similarly, `sass-loader?sourceMap`.

Comment: ok that fixed a lot of the issues, i am getting a Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found.This is where im configuring the postcss in the webpack. in plugins I have

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: __dirname,
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer
        ]
      }
    })

Comment: I think at this point, that's another question and should be raised as such. It would make sense to edit this question to include the first error message, and for answers to deal with that, but it wouldn't make sense for the second error message regarding PostCSS to be included in this question.

Comment: Ok did it thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that webpack loaders must include the `-loader` prefix, the correct modification from `css?sourceMap` is not to `css?sourceMap-loader` but instead to `css-loader?sourceMap`.

Similarly, `sass?sourceMap` must become `sass-loader?sourceMap`.

In both cases, `sourceMap` acts in a similar way to a query string parameter in a URL, and the adjustment from `css` to `css-loader` is akin to a resource moving from `example.com/css` to `example.com/css-loader`.